I'm unable to accessing Codeium chat, Connection Error, Missing chat language server URL?
When I open Codeium Chat window on Android Studio, a Codeium chat window opens and fails to connect,
This is the error:
Connection Error
Missing chat language server URL. Please ensure that you are signed in to the Codeium plugin and close / reopen the chat window. If the problem persists, please restart the IDE.
This is the debug output:
{ "url": "http://127.0.0.1:49814/?api_key=0511b268-a1e8-40ba-abc7-abffe568ee79", "connection": { "status": "CONNECTING", "error": { "name": "Error", "message": "Missing chat language server URL. Please ensure that you are signed in to the Codeium plugin and close / reopen the chat window. If the problem persists, please restart the IDE." } }, "isChatEnabled": false, "handshake": {}, "params": { "ideTelemetryEnabled": false, "ready": true, "apiKey": "0511b268-a1e8-40ba-abc7-abffe568ee79", "hasDevExtension": false, "hasEnterpriseExtension": false, "hasIndexService": false, "diffViewEnabled": false, "openFilePointerEnabled": false, "insertAtCursorEnabled": false }, "data": { "numMessages": 0 }, "bridge": { "bridgeType": "null" }, "health": { "checkStatus": null, "error": { "name": "TypeError", "message": "Failed to fetch" } } }
Is anyone else facing this issue or found the solution?
I tried restarting the PC, Android studio, reinstalling the plugin and logging in again.
I also tried the Retry Connection button in order to use Codeium chat in Android Studio.

Same error for me in PhpStorm.
